# Google Chrome bug not loading google maps, jQuery functions on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

Here is my problem. First I load the site and everything works fine. Then I click on a link and it calls Ajax for new page. Data that is returned contains HTML and Javascript. Some javascript functions works fine, like click function. But google maps don't want to load, mouseover functions works but doesn't want to show/hide ( btw alert function works).

But there is a trick. If I open Developer Tools (right click -> inspect), somehow google maps shows up and functions start working.

I know this is a bug, does anyone know how to go around it?

And there is a Warning: `(2) event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.` I have jQuery version 1.7.1.

Comment: The warning is nothing to do with your code - it's just alerting you that webkit is removing those properties from the global event object soon

Comment: Do you have an example page posted somewhere we can look at?

Comment: I fixed it. Guess empty progress tag was the problem for not loading show/hide function and google maps.

Comment: I love how Google is not giving a f**k about the developers, who have to maintain their apps daily to keep them working. Long story short about people stupidity and Google reliability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was empty `<progress>` tag.
When I removed it from my form, everything was working normaly. Strange.